# How to save picture using ionic camera preview

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm developing a mobile application using Ionic 4. Everything is working smoothly, but i could not save the picture when i call the function `takePicture()`. Does it have any parameters like `saveToPhotoAlbum` in Ionic Camera Plugin. Do help me out.

```js
  cameraPictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    quality: 100
  }

  takePicture() {
    let result = this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.cameraPictureOpts);
    let picture = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${result}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image in a local variable.

```
selectedImage: any; 

pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    quality: 85
};

............


takePicture() {
    console.log('take pinture');
    // take a picture
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
      this.selectedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      console.log('take picture ');
      this.location.back(); // go to previous page
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.selectedImage = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
    });
  }`
```

Once saved in the variable you can save it to the phone, for example using [NativeStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage).

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

 constructor(private storage: NativeStorage) {}

saveImage() {
    this.storage.setItem('image', {property: this.selectedImage})
              .then(
                  () => {
                    console.log('Stored image!');
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.error('Error guardando la imagen', error);
                  }
          );
}
```

Comment: I Tried this now, still i could not find the saved image in the gallery.

Comment: See the github link of native storage, it states data will be lost once app is uninstalled. "Save data over multiple sessions, i.e. holds the data till the application is removed from the device". Link : "https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage"

Comment: Native storage usually saves the data in the phone until you uninstall the application, but not in the gallery. to save the photos in the gallery, take a look at this pugin [base64-to-gallery](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64-to-gallery)

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you. In addition you also need to ask for storage permission manually for android.

Answer (score 0):

The ionic/native CameraPlugin .takePicture() method returns a promise. To get the value you need to change your code a bit.

```
  takePicture() {
    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.cameraPictureOpts).then(data => {
         let picture = `data:image/jpeg;base64,` + data;
    });

  }
```

Comment: I already have the value. What i need is to save the captured image to the gallery of my mobile device.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what 'save' meant in your question. To save a picture in the gallery you should look up the plugin base64-to-gallery https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64-to-gallery. The instructions there should help you out.